# How to configure the hidden class in the rows of a table?

Tags: javascript, html, hidden

I have a table that I'm manipulating through a static js file. I made a filter to show only the lines that contain the values ​​typed in the input. For that, I add the 'hidden' class to those that don't contain the value typed in the input. However, when I go to inspect, only the first line is configured with the "hidden" class. How do I do it for all the other lines that don't contain the values ​​typed in the input?

The code:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <hr>
  <form class="form-search">
    <input class="form-control" id="form-control" type="text" name="fitrar" placeholder="Buscar Registros"
      autocomplete="off" autofocus />
    <a href="{% url 'registros' %}" id="id_btnlimpar" class="btn btn-light">Limpar</a>
  </form>
  </hr>
  <table class="table table-dark">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">CNPJ</th>
        <th scope="col">CPF</th>
        <th scope="col">Nome</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for registro in registros %}
      <tr>
        <td scope="row">{{ registro.id }}</td>
        <td scope="row"><a href="#modal{{registro.id}}" data-toggle="modal">{{ registro.cnpj }}</a></td>
        <td scope="row">{{ registro.cpf }}</td>
        <td scope="row">{{ registro.nome }}</td>
      </tr>
```

JS:

```
const inputSearchRegistros = document.querySelector('.form-search input')
const tableRegistros = document.querySelector('.table tbody tr')

inputSearchRegistros.addEventListener('input', event => {
    const inputValue = event.target.value.trim()
    Array.from(tableRegistros.children)
        .filter(regs => !regs.textContent.includes(inputValue))
        .forEach(regs => {
            regs.classList.add('hidden')
        })
})
```

Result:

```
<tr>
   <td scope="row" class="hidden">1</td>
   <td scope="row" class="hidden"><a href="#modal1" data-toggle="modal">31024483000198</a></td>
   <td scope="row" class="hidden">86520083534</td>
   <td scope="row" class="hidden">Adriana teste esteves</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td scope="row">2</td>
    <td scope="row"><a href="#modal2" data-toggle="modal">31024483000198</a></td>
    <td scope="row">86520083534</td>
    <td scope="row">Adriana teste esteves</td>
</tr>
```

They are the same values, but only the first line receives the hidden class

I would like all lines that do not have the values ​​typed in the input to receive the hidden class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

querySelector only returns the first element that matches the selector even if there is more than one match. You want to use querySelectorAll like this

```
const tableRegistros = document.querySelectorAll('.table tbody tr')
```

You'll then have to loop through the results like in ryan's answer or select the td elements and loop through those like this depending on what your trying to accomplish

```js
    const tableRegistros = document.querySelectorAll('.table tbody tr td')

    inputSearchRegistros.addEventListener('input', event => {
        const inputValue = event.target.value.trim()
        Array.from(tableRegistros)
            .filter(regs => !regs.textContent.includes(inputValue))
            .forEach(regs => {
                regs.classList.add('hidden')
            })
    })
```

Comment: Your solution still applies the class to the `td`. The entire row needs to be hidden.

Comment: according to the op he was trying to add the class to the td

Comment: The OP refers to "lines", which is most likely referencing "rows" and not individual cells. The code in his question only worked for the first "line"... even though it was the first 4 cells that were hidden. He specifically asked for it to work for "all lines", not just the first one.

Comment: ya, its a guess as to what he means though. Hence why i put see ryan's solution or select the td elements depending on what your trying to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

1. You are using `document.querySelector`, which will only select the first row. You want to use `document.querySelectorAll`
2. You are iterating over the table cells using `Array.from(tableRegistros.children)`.

```js
// this only selects the first row
const tableRegistros = document.querySelector('.table tbody tr'); 

// this is a bunch of td elements
Array.from(tableRegistros.children)
```

Instead, you want to iterate over all of the rows, and then all of the cells in each row:

```js
// use querySelectorAll to select all rows
const tableRegistros = document.querySelectorAll('.table tbody tr');

// Iterate each row
tableRegistros.forEach(row => {
  // Then search all of the cells for the content
  const containsText = Array.from(row.children).some(cell => cell.textContent.includes(inputValue));
  if (!containsText) {
    row.classList.add('hidden');
  } else {
    row.classList.remove('hidden');
  }
});
```

Comment: But inputValue returns a null value that way, doesn't it?

Comment: I didn't include all of the code you need. You still need to add the event listener to your input. I was just showing the code that was wrong.